# GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES is not working for me

Tags: mysql, sql

```sql
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database.* TO 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

I got the ERROR

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' at line 1

Comment: Which MySQL version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You can create user first and then grant

```
CREATE USER 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL ON database.* TO 'username'@'localhost';
```

Should work.

[Source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html).